# main.vb, main.designer.vb and missing Form Designer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have been working with "visual basic.net" on a "windows forms" application.  While manipulating controls and adding event handlers I noticed the resultant code was being generated within a file named 'main.designer.vb'.  However, if I look in the solution explorer for my project there is no 'main.designer.vb' file, just 'main.vb'.

This is not a colossal problem as it runs properly.  However, having closed the 'form designer' window I now cannot reopen it!  'main.vb' has no option to 'view in form designer'.

Any advice on this?

Would it be possible to copy the contents of 'main.designer.vb' in to 'main.vb' and delete 'main.designer.vb' entirely?  If I did this, the next time I manipulated the form would the code be added to 'main.vb' or would a new 'main.designer.vb' be created?

Comment: what is your Visual Studio version? you should tag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have sorted out the problem.

'main.vb' was completely empty.  All the code I had generated and written directly was inside 'main.designer.vb'.  However, once I made a class definition within 'main.vb':

```
Public Class main

End Class
```

and then cut/pasted all my custom event handler code and subroutines from 'main.designer.vb' to THAT class - all was well.  'main.vb' now shows the correct form icon and FINALLY offers the correct 'view designer' context menu option.

I am not sure why it happened in the first place though.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio. In the toolbar in this window is a button called "Show all files". Click it. 
Then every file in the projects folder is actually shown in the solution explorer. Expand the treenodes for the form and you will see the designer.vb.

There are also buttons for switching between code-view and designer view. Just remember to select the form in the solution explorer for the buttons to show the correct form in the designer.

Comment: On clicking that button 'main.designer.vb' does indeed appear - along with a file called 'main.resx'- as 'child' items of 'main.vb'.  However, this icon is not a form icon nor does it have a context menu entry for 'view in designer'.  A double click merely brings up a code view window for it but no form designer...  Looking closely at 'main.designer.vb', I find it DOES indeed have an 'Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form' command which is another tip I have found on the net - which if missing could cause this problem.  A bit frustrating this one!!!

Comment: I can reopen the designer view just by double-clicking the form in the list. Did you try that?

Comment: I did Jens - but it seems without the 'main' class being defined inside 'main.vb' then the IDE itself did not work properly.  So far as the code itself went it ran fine - but I think the mechanisms inside VS were not properly identifying where classes and forms were kept.  Once I put a 'main' class inside 'main.vb' then it began working as it should.  The definition in 'main.designer.vb' was specifically `partial class main` but I don't understand VB.NET well enough yet to properly appreciate that distinction from `public class main`.  Anyway MANY thanks for all the suggestions and ideas.